# What does Model.(Variable) do?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-web-developer

Okay, so I've got this code:

```
    public ActionResult Welcome(string name = "", int numTimes = 1)
    {
        var viewModel = new WelcomeViewModel
        {
            Message = "Hello " + name,
            NumTimes = numTimes
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
    public class WelcomeViewModel
    {
        public string Message { get; set; }
        public int NumTimes { get; set; }
    }
```

and the view in Welcome() is:

```
<h2>Welcome</h2>

<% for(int i = 0; i < Model.NumTimes; i++) {%>

    <h3><%: Model.Message; %></h3>
<%} %>
```

Firstly, when I run this, I get an error when running .../Welcome?name=Scott&numtimes=4 saying that in the line

```
<h3><%: Model.Message; %></h3>
```

it expects ')'

> Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 
>   Compiler Error Message: CS1026: ) expected

why is this?

---

Secondly what is this whole Model thing? What does it do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the `<%: Model.Message; %>` translates (basically) into:

```
Response.Write(Model.Message;);
```

As you see, the semicolon should not be there. The compiler expects the ending parentheses before there is a semicolon, hence the error message.

The "Model thing" is the M in MVC. The Model is the data that the View displays. Each view has a single Model, so the Model contains all the data that the View needs.

Comment: Just to clarify it actually translates to `Response.Write(html_encode(Model.Message;));` as it's `<%: %>` not `<%= %>`

Comment: @Basiclife: Yes, that is correct, but that's where the "basically" comes in because it's not really relevant to the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't need to put the semi-colon after `Model.Message`.

Model is the reference to what you supplied to your view, in your controller. That's the same instance as what you type `return View(viewModel);` in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

With regards to your second question, MVC is a way of separating the logic (in your controller) from the presentation (in your view).

You use the controller to generate a model which contains all the information required by the view.

Eg for a form, the model would have a field for each input. For a table, it would have an `IEnumerable<SomeRowClass>` etc...

The view itself should do as little processing as possible - simple if statements and loops. all actual logic should be constrained to the controller.

One way to think of it is that a developer writes the controller, a designer writes the view and they collaborate for what goes in the model - designer says "I need to know X,Y,Z" - so the developer adds them to the model and populates the fields as appropriate

As mentioned in the other answer, the semicolon after `Model.Message` is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the misplaced semicolon, make sure your view is defined to inherit from `ViewPage<WelcomeViewModel>`. This specifies the type that `Model` has within the view, allowing the compiler to resolve its members (`Message`, `NumTimes`).